# Javascript difficulty - parameter passed to inner function and the use of parenthesis

Tags: javascript, closures, parentheses, arrow-functions

Could someone kindly demystify the following?

```
const connection = (closure) => {
    return mongoClient.connect(connectionString,(err,db) => {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        closure(db);
    });
};
```

Apparently:

1. the 'connection' constant is storing a function which takes a parameter (closure)
2. mongoClient.connect() returns null but in turn populates the parameters inside the callback.
3. If an error occurs err logs to the console but nonetheless (and here is the most confusing part) closure makes use of parenthesis to wrap itself around db which gives?
4. Since connect() returns null, could this have been replaced with some assignment statement (such as closure = db;) and then the return statement removed?  What is the need of a return statement here?

Thanks for everything 
Al

Comment: "*closure makes use of parenthesis to wrap itself around db*" - what? It's a function call. And no, it doesn't happen when the error is logged, because the function `return`s in the `if` block. Admittedly, using `if (err) console.log(err); else closure(db);` would have been cleaner.

Comment: so is there a hidden else in the version i presented? Thank you for your reply. I thought it was a short-hand if (only) block

Comment: No, there is no hidden `else`. There's a `return` inside the `if`, which causes the statement after the short-hand if to be not reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If an error occurs err logs to the console but nonetheless (and here is the most confusing part) ***closure makes use of parenthesis to wrap itself around db which gives?***

Not "nonetheless". The `closure` line only happens when there's no error, because if there was, the function returned immediately.

Also, the parentheses after `closure` are just invoking it, so `closure` is expected to be a function. Whatever it returns will be its result.

> Since connect() returns null, could this have been replaced with some assignment statement (such as closure = db;) and then the return statement removed? What is the need of a return statement here?

The `return` is only to exit the function. The fact that it's returning the result of `console.log` doesn't mean much here. They only did that to get it into a single statement so that they didn't need curly braces.

```
const connection = (closure) => {
    return mongoClient.connect(connectionString,(err,db) => {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        closure(db);
    });
};
```

I assume you were referring to the innermost `return`. The outer one can make no use of `db` because it only exists inside the callback passed to `connect`. If `.connect()` always returns `null`, then yes, there's no need for that outer `return`, but again, you can't just use `db`. The rest of the code is still necessary.

To be clear, you can not get any value back from the callback passed to `connect`. It is invoked long after your outer function and `.connect()` return.